# JQuery ajax event "on drop" doesn't works

Tags: jquery, ajax, drag-and-drop

I got a list of images in a `<ul><li>` width the id of the element.
Now i just want after dropping a image in another place, that the $.ajax is firing but it does not work.
Here the HTML Code:

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js'>
    </script> 
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js'>
    </script>
 
  <style>
    .dd{
      list-style-type:none;
      cursor:move;
      display:inline-block;
    }
  </style>
<div id="image-container">
      <div id="txtresponse" > 
        <form method="post" action="https://example.com/script.php">
          
          <ul id="image-list" >
            <li class="dd" id="image_1" >
              <img src="path/to/image/image1.jpg">
              Image 1
            </li>
            <li class="dd" id="image_2" >
              <img src="path/to/image/image2.jpg">
              Image 2
            </li>
            <li class="dd" id="image_3" >
              <img src="path/to/image/image3.jpg">
              Image 3
            </li>
            <li class="dd" id="image_4" >
              <img src="path/to/image/image4.jpg">
              Image 4
            </li>
        </ul>
        </form>
       </div>
      </div>
```

Here The Javascript for drag & drop

```
<script language='javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function () {
          var dropIndex;
          $("#image-list").sortable({
            update: function(event, ui) {
              dropIndex = ui.item.index();
            }
          });
     
           $('html').on('drop',function(e) {
           alert('ajax goes here');
         });
```

If i use a `$('#submit').click(function (e) {`
every thing works but not with a **on('drop')**
Why there is no reaction on that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `stop:` after your `update:`

There's much more to the [UI Sortable Library](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) as well ...  Lots of goodies, worth a read.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dropIndex;
  $("#image-list").sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
      dropIndex = ui.item.index();
    },
    stop: function() {
      alert('ajax goes here');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.dd {
  list-style-type: none;
  cursor: move;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js'>
</script>
<div id="image-container">
  <div id="txtresponse">
    <form method="post" action="https://example.com/script.php">

      <ul id="image-list">
        <li class="dd" id="image_1">
          <img src="path/to/image/image1.jpg"> Image 1
        </li>
        <li class="dd" id="image_2">
          <img src="path/to/image/image2.jpg"> Image 2
        </li>
        <li class="dd" id="image_3">
          <img src="path/to/image/image3.jpg"> Image 3
        </li>
        <li class="dd" id="image_4">
          <img src="path/to/image/image4.jpg"> Image 4
        </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```